# Call determinated actuator for Traits

Tags: google-assistant-sdk

I've a doubt... i'm starting with assistant SDK, and I dont know how make a differece between several actuators.

I've seen in google's guide how it works, but there I only can see the code for one actuator.

```
print('Do command', command, 'with params', str(params)) # Add the following:
if command == "action.devices.commands.OnOff":
    if params['on']:
        print('Turning the LED on.')
    else:
        print('Turning the LED off.')
```

My problem is that dont undertand how works the "if command" ... because here its only cheking if arrives from recognition "On" or "Off" but not define the destiny.

Supose that we have 2 independent lights... this code will turn on and off both at the same time. Although then in GPIO configuration I'll put 2 differents outputs the condition will be the same.

I should declare my actuators before and then change "action.devices.commands.OnOff" by "action.actuator1.commands.OnOff" and "action.actuator2.commands.OnOff" ?

Thanks a lot for any help... sorry if I did not explain myself well

Answer (score 0):

If you want to control two separate subcomponents, you will want to create [custom device actions](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/device-actions-overview) with a pattern that includes a parameter for which item you want to turn on/off.

Comment: Would i need a different custom device action for each subcomponent?

Comment: Not necessarily. You can have each actuator be defined as a parameter.

Comment: So... Can I have several OnOff instructions only changing the device? As I thought before?action.actuator1.commands.OnOff" and "action.actuator2.commands.OnOff" ... Or what is the structure... Im little lost

Comment: Follow [this guide](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/guides/service/python/extend/custom-actions) to create custom device actions.

Comment: Thanks dude!... I'll try it